# Terraform: What is the simplest way to Incrementally add servers to a deployment?

Tags: terraform, devops

I am a newbie with terraform so don´t laugh :) I want to deploy a number of instances of a server, then add their IPs to a Route53 hosted zone. I will be using Terraform v0.12.24 no chance of 0.14 at the moment.

So far, I have working the "easy", spaghetti approach:

[image]

- module server: buys and creates a list of servers
- module route53: adds route53 records, parameter=aray of ips

main.tf

```
module "hostedzone" {
  source = "./route53"
  ncs_domain = var.ncs_domain
}

module "server" {
  source = "./server"
  name = "${var.ncs_hostname}-${var.ncs_id}"
  hcloud_token = var.server_htk
  servers = [
    {
      type = "cx11",
      location = "fsn1",
    },
    {
      type = "cx11",
      location = "fsn1",
    }
  ]
}

resource "aws_route53_record" "server1-record" {
  zone_id = module.hostedzone.zone.zone_id
  name = "${var.ncs_hostname}.${var.ncs_domain}"
  type = "A"
  ttl = "300"
  records = module.server.server.*.ipv4_address
}
```

and the relevant server resource array:

```
resource "hcloud_server" "apiserver" {
  count = length(var.servers)
  # Create a server
  name = "${var.name}-${count.index}"
  # Name server
  image = var.image
  # Basic image
  server_type = var.servers[count.index].type
  # Instance type
  location = var.servers[count.index].location
}
```

So if I run `terraform apply`, I get the server array created. Cool !

Now, I would like to be able to run this module to create and destroy specific servers on demand, like:

- initially deploy the platform with one or two servers.
- remove one of the initial servers in the array
- add new servers

So, how could I use this incrementally, that is, without providing the whole array of servers everytime? Like just adding one to the existing list, or remove other.

Comment: Does https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/terraform/count work for you?

Comment: Then just adjust the count any time you want to change the number of servers.

Comment: thanks for your pointers, I was able to transform it into building an array of servers that is passed as parameter (see edit). But my problem is the same, is it pssible to run it incrementally rather than creating everything at once?

Comment: if you have the state file from a previous run, terraform should work out which servers you have and automatically only create/delete the difference. If you want to specify that explicitly, terraform is probably the wrong tool.

Comment: I finally pass always the whole array from the tool client, where it can be edited, and indeed, terraform figures outwhat to add or remove from the previous state. Thanks !